# I see a question's status, active: today but didn't see any activity for the day

Tags: support, specific-question, last-activity

Today I see a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102465/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-null) in the [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tab.

When I open the question, I see its status is **active today**. So I thought some change was made to the question today.

> [image: Active Today]

But I didn't see any newly added comments, answers, or edits.

**Comments section:**

> [image: Active Comments]

**Answers section:**

> [image: Active Answers]

What is the reason behind the active status?

Comment: [CommunityUser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) must of bumped it. "Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention". Please note that this user does not leave any traces for us when she bumps those questions.

Comment: @Dronehinge: Oh, old **unanswered** questions! Got it.

Comment: Not an unanswered question but a question having no upvoted answer or an accepted answer.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Okay.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @AzizShaikh see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482537/how-to-check-that-the-string-is-not-nil-in-swift) I saw it on my feed, saying "modified 33 mins ago Amit Verma 7" yet nothing is changed, nor there is any mention of an edit by "Amit Veram". Neither I see any trace of community user...

Comment: @Honey Amit Verma posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/) at 2017-01-05 11:07:45Z which he later deleted. This answer is now visible only to users with 10K+ reps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That particular **question was bumped** by the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

> [image]

Community user randomly [poke old unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)* every hour so they get some attention.

<sub>* Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that.</sub>

If a post gets bumped by the community user then a [banner is displayed under the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287445/) and it is also [recorded in the post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287656/).

**Banner:**

> [image]

**Revision History:**

> [image: Revision History]

**Post Timeline:**

> [image: Timeline]

Note: Storing bump record with the timeline was implemented in 2016. This record is not available for older posts.

---

Another possible reason for seeing a recent activity in a post could be a deleted answer. Someone may have posted a new answer but got deleted either by OP or privileged users. This answer is then visible only to users with 10K+ reps.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482537/how-to-check-that-the-string-is-not-nil-in-swift) I saw it on my feed, saying "modified 33 mins ago Amit Verma 7" yet nothing is changed, nor there is any mention of an edit by "Amit Veram". Neither I see any trace of community user...

Comment: @Honey Amit Verma posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/) at 2017-01-05 11:07:45Z which he later deleted. This answer is now visible only to users with 10K+ reps.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing [`Dronehinge`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3041194/dronehinge)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297108/i-see-a-questions-status-active-today-but-didnt-see-any-activity-for-the-da?noredirect=1#comment207789_297108), I revisit the `interesting` tab to check the question's detail.

I see the question is modified by [`Community`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)

[image: Active Modified]

Answer (score 2):

There are comments on the question suggesting there was no trace of the question being bumped, so not sure if the behaviour has changed since that time but thought I'd post an answer.

I just experienced this today and was confused until I clicked the edit history link (the link labelled "edited Jul 13 '14 at 22:54" in the screenshot above):

[image: screenshot of edit history showing "bumped by community user"]

Comment: Yes, this changed recently. It used to be that the bump would leave no trace. Only recently does the bump leave a record in the revisions.